# Neater way of converting an integer time/date to a string

Tags: python, date, time

I am fairly new to python and would like to write a program that will need to convert between a string and integer representation of a date and time.

The format, is fixed and must look like "02.03.2010 13:32:20"

Is there a neater way than the following?

```
class TimeStamp:
    def __init__(self, day, month, year, hour, minute, second):
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.second = second

    def __repr__(self):
        string = ""
        if self.day < 10:
            string += "0" + str(self.day)
        else:
            string += str(self.day)
        string += "."
        if self.month < 10:
            string += "0" + str(self.month)
        else:
            string += str(self.month)
        string += "."
        if self.year < 10:
            string += "0" + str(self.year)
        else:
            string += str(self.year)
        string += " "
        if self.hour < 10:
            string += "0" + str(self.hour)
        else:
            string += str(self.hour)
        string += ":"
        if self.hour < 10:
            string += "0" + str(self.hour)
        else:
            string += str(self.hour)
        string += ":"
        if self.hour < 10:
            string += "0" + str(self.hour)
        else:
            string += str(self.hour)
        return string
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `datetime`/`date` modules?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `datetime` module instead; it's [`.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) can easily meet your needs and more.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
'08.07.2012 14:43:58'
>>> datetime(2010, 3, 2, 13, 32, 20).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
'02.03.2010 13:32:20'
```